# Symfony 3.4.6 - "Token "XXXXXX" was not found in the database."

Tags: php, csrf, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm attempting to test and debug a Symfony web app.  When viewing the site using the `app_dev.php` front controller/environment, the web debug toolbar doesn't load, and when I click on 'Open the web profiler', I get the following error:

> Token "XXXXX" was not found in the database

*Note: it's not the literal value of XXXXX, but that the token it's looking for changes every time I try to open the profiler.

I also cannot log into the administration area of the site, likely because of this token error.

I think it may be an issue with how my `security.yml` is set up, but nothing jumps out at me.  Here it is:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The associated snippet in `config.yml`:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: noreply@someplace.com
        sender_name: 'someplace'
```

And, for completeness' sake, the part that references the toolbar in `config_dev.yml`:

```
framework:
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing_dev.yml'
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Finally, given that FOSUserBundle is my user provider, I also executed `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  It was a combination of an incompletely installed service having an entry in `services.yml`, yet missing files, and the wrong permissions/ownership for my `/var` directory.  I have a separate linux user for all of my apps to emulate what's on the production server (each site gets its own PHP-FPM pool, and none have root or sudo privileges).

So, with that said, commenting out the incomplete service in `services.yml` and running `$ sudo chown -R siteuser:siteuser /path/to/this/site/project` did the trick.